# How to get the background color from a Conditional Formatting in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to obtain the cell background color assigned using a conditional formatting rule in Excel in my VBA script. I realized that using `Range.Interior.Color` property doesn't have the color resulting of an applied conditional formatting feature from Excel.

I did some research and I found this long way [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm), it compiles and runs but I don't get the assigned color [I get always (255,255,255)]

I am using Excel 2016 and I am wondering if there is a simpler way to obtain this information using some built-in VBA function or using any other excel trick.

Comment: `Range.Interior.Color` will output he color as long. [`Range.interior.colorindex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff840443.aspx) is probably the think you looking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to know the color of a cell that **has been colored** by a conditional formatting rule (CFR) then use `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`¹.

If you want to definitively know what color a cell **may or may not have been colored** by a CFR you need to iterate through the CFRs that could be affecting that cell and look at each of the `Range.FormatConditions(*x*).Interior.Color`.

**Documentation:** [`range.DisplayFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)

¹ <sub>Note: `.DisplayFormat` is not available for a worksheet UDF.</sub>

Comment: In my case after a conditional formating couldn't get to identify the Font colors with vba code, but this did the trick, using the "DisplayFormat.Font.Color" worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` does not work.  It breaks the macro without any error message.

Comment: I've read the referenced documentation, but it is not clear to me in what contexts .DisplayFormat is available.  Is it only available in SUB definitions?  Or is it available in FUNCTION definitions as long as the function is not called from a cell formula?

Answer (score 12):

The code below gives the **HEX** and **RGB** value of the range whether **formatted using conditional formatting** or otherwise. If the range is not formatted using Conditional Formatting and you intend to use iColor function in the Excel as UDF. It won't work. Read the below excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel).

*Note that the **DisplayFormat** property does not work in user defined functions. For example, in a worksheet function that returns the interior color of a cell, if you use a line similar to:*

```
Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
```

*then the worksheet function executes to return a #VALUE! error.*

```
Public Function iColor(rng As Range, Optional formatType As String) As Variant
'formatType: Hex for #RRGGBB, RGB for (R, G, B) and IDX for VBA Color Index
    Dim colorVal As Variant
    colorVal = rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Select Case UCase(formatType)
        Case "HEX"
            iColor = "#" & Format(Hex(colorVal Mod 256),"00") & _
                           Format(Hex((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256),"00") & _
                           Format(Hex((colorVal \ 65536)),"00")
        Case "RGB"
            iColor = Format((colorVal Mod 256),"00") & ", " & _
                     Format(((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256),"00") & ", " & _
                     Format((colorVal \ 65536),"00")
        Case "IDX"
            iColor = rng.Interior.ColorIndex
        Case Else
            iColor = colorVal
    End Select
End Function

'Example use of the iColor function
Sub Get_Color_Format()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Selection.Cells
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = iColor(rng, "HEX")
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = iColor(rng, "RGB")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the function - i've reused it but ran into an error with some `HEX` values. if they were `0` the function would return just `0` but in fact for it to be valid it needs to be `00`. To fix this I replaced the Hex values with `Format(Hex(colorVal....), "00")`

Comment: That's very valuable info. I have amended the code.

Answer (score 6):

You want `Range.DisplayFormat` if you need to account for Conditional Formatting

(added in Excel 2010)

Comment: Note: .DisplayFormat is not available for a worksheet UDF.

Answer (score -4):

.FormatCondition property of range or selection should help with any formatting
Use With...End With

If you want to know the exact color RGB values, u can just try recording macro and get the rgb values.

Comment: The original question already [refers](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm) to a solution that uses `.FormatCondition`. I was looking for something simpler, such the marked as the best answer.