# VBA check if cells in range are red then exit sub

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to create a macro that performs a check on a range that if a cell is formatted as red (based on conditional formatting) then stop the sub... otherwise continue.

```
Sub O_Upload()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+U

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, 
wbactive As Workbook, wsactive As Worksheet, lstrow As Long
Set Wb1 = Workbooks("spreadsheet.xlsx")
Set ws1 = Wb1.Sheets("Stage 1 Trim")
Set ws2 = Wb1.Sheets("Stage 2 Data Validation")
Set ws3 = Wb1.Sheets("_1010u Sheet")
Set wbactive = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsactive = wbactive.Sheets("Data")

wsactive.range("B10").Select
lstrow = Selection.End(xlDown).Row

wsactive.range("A10:V" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=ws1.range("A4")
ws1.range("X4:AS" & lstrow).Copy
ws2.range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'add red validation check
'if red stop
'if green copy to ws3
Dim cel As range
For Each cel In ws2.range("A3:V" & lstrow)
 If cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
  MsgBox ("Data contains errors!"), vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If
Next

ws2.range("A3:V" & lstrow).Copy
ws3.range("B13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
MsgBox "Data is ready to be uploaded", vbOKOnly


End Sub
```

The error i'm getting is on line -For Each cel In ws2.range("A3:V" & lstrow)
I appreciate the help.

Comment: What is the value of `lstrow` at that point?

Comment: 130...but can be up to 500 depending on the size of the spreadsheet document.

Comment: I'm not asking what it *should* be, but what it *is* when the error occurs. One way to find out is put `MsgBox  lstrow` as the line before where the error occurs. It will display the value of `lstrow`

Comment: My b... lstrow is set to 139 when the error occurs. thanks.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: corresponding answer fixed my problem. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributing  [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122782/how-to-get-the-background-color-from-a-conditional-formatting-in-excel-using-vba/50479544#50479544) for details.

Kindly replace the code

```
cel.Interior.Color
```

with this:

```
cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

Comment: Bonus: You can replace RGB(255, 0, 0) with vbRed. It makes code more readable and understandable to newbies.