Average of Conditionally Formatted cells by color
I have a dataset (below) in excel that is conditionally formatted using the excel pre-set GREEN-YELLOW-RED color scale. What I want to do is find the average based by color of cell...and the whole point is that I want the nuance of the different shades of colors.
I have the below VBA module that does the average based by color done by hand...but not by conditionally formatted color. Any ideas?
Function AvgCellsByColor(CellRange As Range, CellColor As Range)

Dim CellColorValue As Integer
Dim RunningAvg As Long
Dim RunningSum As Long
Dim RunngingCount As Long

CellColorValue = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set i = CellRange

For Each i In CellRange
    If i.Interior.ColorIndex = CellColorValue Then
    RunningSum = RunningSum + i.Value
    RunningCount = RunningCount + 1
    End If
Next i

AvgCellsByColor = RunningSum / RunningCount

End Function



You can get the cell color with Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123047/7599798), but be aware that there are different colors for every distinct value - even if they look the same.

You could convert each cell's DisplayFormat.Interior.Color value to RGB values and then average those out.. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24132665/7446760

Would it be possible to use the same selection criteria?  for example, range a1:c2, with >=1 and <=4, would be an array formula like so =SUM(($A$1:$C$2)*($A$1:$C$2>=1)*($A$1:$C$2<=4))/SUM(($A$1:$C$2>=1)*($A$1:$C$2<=4))
