How to get HEX color value from cell color?
I want to get HEX color value from cell (range) color.
The following links are giving wrong results.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216193/13075931
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479544/13075931
You can find detailed explanation in the following picture.

Update: Thanks for good answers but I have found better solutions in the following link.
https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html

The first link provides a partial explanation in the discussion: an RGB value in VBA is formatted differently from the HEX value in the color picker. In VBA, the B is the most significant part. There is an error in the answer provided in your second link; I just left a comment there.

Simpler
Function GetColorInHex(cc As Range) As String
  Dim s As String
  s = Hex(cc.Cells(1).Interior.Color)
  s = String(6 - Len(s), "0") & s
  GetColorInHex = Right(s, 2) & Mid(s, 3, 2) & Left(s, 2)
End Function


This provides the RGB hex values in the correct order and with two digits each (ie for each color):
Function GetHexColor(cel As Range) As String
    If cel.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim lColorNum As Long, iRed As Integer, iGreen As Integer, iBlue As Integer
    lColorNum = cel.Interior.Color
    iRed = lColorNum And 255
    iGreen = lColorNum \ 256 And 255
    iBlue = lColorNum \ 256 ^ 2 And 255
    GetHexColor = Right$("0" & Hex(iRed), 2) & Right$("0" & Hex(iGreen), 2) & Right$("0" & Hex(iBlue), 2)
End Function

... returning 750D02 and AE0F21 for the two colors in your linked 'detailed explanation'.
