VBA function to check colour of conditionally formatted cell in another workbook?
I've found some useful questions on this topic, such as this one here. However, none of the solutions appear to work when checking cells in another workbook.
Is there a way to check the background colour of a conditionally formatted cell from another workbook?
If it makes it easier, I just need to know if a colour has been applied, rather than the specific colour.
Many thanks.

The solution is easy. Don't check the color, use the formatting condition (formula) instead!

I agree with rotabor, don't put logic into color, logic is within the data and coloring is just a method to display it. That said: To get the color of a cell that might be set by conditional formatting, use Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123047/7599798

Is this "another workbook" open or closed?

Always helps to show the code you actually tried - the question you link to has multiple methods.
