Is there any way to modify cell values ​in one column based on the background color of cells in another column?
I usually use conditional formatting on entire columns, formatting cells in column F in red (255, 199, 206) and green (198, 239, 206) - and then manually modifying the values ​​of the cells in column I based on these formatting (0 for cells in the same row as cells formatted in red; 5000 for cells in the same row as cells formatted in green).

The problem is that the spreadsheets are too big and I need to find a way to modify the cells in column I more quickly or automatically, so that the value of the cells in column I in the same row as the cells in column F with a red background is modified to 0; and the value of the cells in column I in the same row as the cells in column F with a green background is changed to 5000.
I tried Python codes, macros and extensions, but nothing had any effect.
Code tried in VBA (I'm not skilled with VBA code, so there may be obvious errors - As I mentioned, I didn't have efficient results in this attempt. VBA just highlights the first line of code in yellow, but I can't find the error that stops me from modify the values that i want.):
Sub ModifyValuesBasedOnColor()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Set the active worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Find the last row in column F
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each cell in column F
    For Each cell In ws.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
        ' Check if the cell's fill color is red (255, 199, 206 in RGB)
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) Then
            ws.Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value = 0
        ' Check if the cell's fill color is green (198, 239, 206 in RGB)
        ElseIf cell.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206) Then
            ws.Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value = 5000
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


Your code cannot work since the colors are changed by Conditional Formatting while the code checks the colors manually set. Since you have many rows, a code that might work would take 'forever'. Anyway, you should use the condition (formula) to change the values. Please share the formulas you use with Conditional Formatting so we can offer an efficient solution.

You can't base a function on the colour of a cell (except if you define your function yourself in VBA), but as the colour you referred to is created by conditional formatting, this means that those colours are based on values, so you can base your new colouring scheme on those same values.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122782/how-to-get-the-background-color-from-a-conditional-formatting-in-excel-using-vba

When working with large datasets, loading the data into an array and processing it there is a more efficient approach.
Sub ModifyValuesBasedOnColor()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Set the active worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Find the last row in column F
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Get the data range in column I
    Dim rngI As Range: set rngI = ws.Range("I1:I" & lastRow)
    ' Load data into array
    Dim arrData : arrData = rngI.Value
    Dim iColor As Long, i As Long
    ' Loop through each cell in column F
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        iColor = ws.Cells(i, "F").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        ' Check if the cell's fill color is red (255, 199, 206 in RGB)
        If iColor = RGB(255, 199, 206) Then
            arrData(i, 1) = 0
        ' Check if the cell's fill color is green (198, 239, 206 in RGB)
        ElseIf iColor = RGB(198, 239, 206) Then
            arrData(i, 1)  = 5000
        End If
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet
    rngI.Value = arrData
End Sub

